# How does Dedupe Subscriber resolve the duplicates among email ids used in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I have to  know the working of **Dedupe** subscriber and so that I can make ensure my email process is unique and correct.

Answer (score 1):

It de-dupes by Email Address, not Subscriber Key.  So if you have the same email address with multiple Subscriber Keys, it'll pick one and skip the others.

If there's any question about which one is selected, I'd recommend de-duping your audience with a Query Activity beforehand.

Comment: Clarifying question: does this apply to all email send types?  User-Initiated, guided send & journey builder (triggered)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.